# Twilio programmable sms

Tags: twilio

I am getting below exception while using the twilio programmable sms

```
com.twilio.exception.ApiException: api.twilio.com
at com.twilio.http.NetworkHttpClient.makeRequest(NetworkHttpClient.java:128)
at com.twilio.http.HttpClient.reliableRequest(HttpClient.java:42)
at com.twilio.http.HttpClient.reliableRequest(HttpClient.java:25)
at com.twilio.http.TwilioRestClient.request(TwilioRestClient.java:42)
at com.twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.MessageCreator.create
(MessageCreator.java:391)
at 
com.twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.MessageCreator.create
(MessageCreator.java:25)
at com.twilio.base.Creator.create(Creator.java:45)
at Example.main(Example.java:24)
```

Below is that that i am using

```
import com.twilio.Twilio;
import com.twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.Message;
import com.twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.MessageCreator;
import com.twilio.type.PhoneNumber;
import com.twilio.exception.ApiException;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Example 
{
private final static String ACCOUNT_SID = 
System.getenv("TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID");
private final static String AUTH_TOKEN = System.getenv("TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Twilio.init(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);

    Message sms;
    try {
        sms = Message.creator(new PhoneNumber("+919250057864"), new 
        PhoneNumber("+16672132498"), "").create();
        System.out.println(sms.getSid());
    } catch (ApiException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

I am using twilio-7.15.6-jar-with-dependencies library.

Comment: Looks like you're getting an error from the API when you make the request. Do you have the message from the error available? That should give you more details on the issue. If you share it here, I can help more too.

Comment: Thanks for the response Philnash. It doesnt show any message.

Comment: There is always an error message in an API response that was an error. Check for the `ApiException`'s `code()` as well, that should give you a numerical code that you can look up in the [errors dictionary](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors).

Comment: Also, it looks like you are trying to send a blank message body. That would likely cause an error, have you tried sending an actual body?

Comment: getCode(), getMoreInfo() and getStatusCode() shows null. Added message in the empty message body too.

Comment: You are trying to send from a US number to an Indian number. Do you have [the correct geographical permissions setup to send messages to India](https://www.twilio.com/console/sms/settings/geo-permissions)? Also, if you are using a trial account, have you [verified the number](https://www.twilio.com/console/phone-numbers/verified) you are sending to?